# Really weird perl syntax error adding TO_JSON method to package

Tags: json, perl, cookies, mod-perl

In adding a TO_JSON method (to convert a blessed reference via JSON.pm) into CGI::Cookie if I do this:

```
package CGI::Cookie;
sub TO_JSON {
    return {
        map { name => $_->name,
              value => $_->value,
              domain => $_->domain,
              path => $_->path,
              expires => $_->expires }
            shift
    }
}
```

> syntax error at XXX.pm line 76, near "shift " syntax error at XXX.pm
>   line 77, near "}" Compilation failed in require at (eval 50) line 3.

But if I do this:

```
package CGI::Cookie;
sub TO_JSON {
    return {
        map { ''.'name' => $_->name,
              value => $_->value,
              domain => $_->domain,
              path => $_->path,
              expires => $_->expires }
            shift
    }
}
```

it works

Can't for the life of me figure out why. Also just quoting "name" doesn't help. I *have to* concatenate an empty string for it to work.

I'm mystified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Perl grammar is a bit ambiguous when it comes to blocks and anonymous hashrefs. When Perl cannot guess correctly, you can force the correct interpretation:

- **Hashref**   by `+{ ... }`
- **Codeblock** by `{; ... }`

Forcing the block after `map` to be a codeblock resolves the issue. Previously it thought the block was an anonymous hash, and missed a comma before the `shift`: `map` can be of the form `map EXPR, LIST`, and a hashref is a valid expression.

---

The sub uses misuses `map` to assign one element to `$_`. It would better be written:

```
sub TO_JSON {
    my $o = shift; # my $_ should work as well, but that is beside the point
    return +{
       name    => $o->name,
       value   => $o->value,
       domain  => $o->domain,
       path    => $o->path,
       expires => $o->expires,
    };
}
```

But it could be abbreviated to

```
sub TO_JSON {
    my $o = shift;
    return +{
       map { $_ => $o->$_() } qw/name value domain path expires/
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Very weird though since a codeblock is supposed to be the preferred first argument to map(), I would think that would be the first thing that Perl would assume.

This works as well:

package CGI::Cookie;
sub TO_JSON {
    return {
        map {;name => $_->name,
              value => $_->value,
              domain => $_->domain,
              path => $_->path,
              expires => $_->expires }
            shift
    }
}